# Strange .NET ListView behaviour

Tags: c#, .net, listview

I'm trying to get my head around this behaviour: I have a ListView on a form in LargeIcon View (`System.Windows.Forms.View.LargeIcon`)

This line is in the constructor:

```
this.listView1.LargeImageList.ImageSize = new Size(32, 32);
```

And then this function is called upon a double click:

```
private void listView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.listView1.LargeImageList.ImageSize = new Size(64, 64); 
}
```

When I double click on the listview, the size changes as expected, but the icon I have is taken away, and I just get a big blank space. Even if I set the ImageIndex to use afterwards, it stays blank, and I can't seem to get it displaying again.

I assume I'm doing something wrong (although I guess .NET could be broken). What do I change such that the icon does not disappear?

(I am in .NET 2.0)

Comment: I take it you have an icon of the appropriate size? (64, 64) ?

Comment: No, all the icons are (200,200), but it works in the first place for (32, 32)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are running into this caveat described in MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelist.imagesize.aspx):

> Because setting the ImageSize property
>   causes the handle to be recreated, you
>   should set ImageSize prior to setting
>   the Images property.

Besides, relying on the system to resize the images from 32x32 to 64x64 would naturally result in low quality images.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not concerned about the low-quality images as I'm just prototyping at the moment. It's more just that the images disappear and I can't get them to display again. It appears that the caveat you describe is indeed the problem - would this then mean that I have to recreate the set of images every time I wish to change the size of the icons?